# Smily posted from IOS app not works in web php

Tags: php, android, ios, json

IOS app developer sent me a code for smily and chinese

```
"\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\u597d\u5bb6\u4f19\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d"
```

which is json when i decode it chinese part from json is proper decoded and proper viewable at website whily smily part is not visible while using 
json_decode('"\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\u597d\u5bb6\u4f19\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d"');

i got 
**好家伙**
at web 
while thay posted from app is 
[image]

Comment: Some systems don't support Emoji characters, so you might have to use a library to convert the characters to images/HTML...

Comment: Not some system all the system at web not supports i have decoded back to json string coming from IOS app.
as IOS developer send me json decoded string for emogies is there any way to convert back to emogies on web ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yahoooooooooooooooooooooooo... At last i get the solution of my problem

```
<?php
print_r(json_decode('"\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\u597d\u5bb6\u4f19\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d"'));
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is basically json string you can decode it to find emogies pictures

like

```
<?php
print_r(json_decode('"\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\ud83d\ude18\u597d\u5bb6\u4f19\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d\ud83d\ude0d"'));
?>
```